# Will a const variable in a structure go to RAM upon structure variable initialization?

Tags: c, struct, embedded, constants, stm32

I need an object oriented model for storing some parameters of a series of entities. I am working on an embedded project on STM32 and I have less than 8kB of SRAM. Most of these parameters are constants and I want them saved in the flash instead of RAM. If I declare a struct with const parameters, will they go to the RAM upon structure initialization?

Comment: Possibly, or they may go in rodata section that is usually located into a flash segment.  Your map file will tell you and, if the data is not in the flash segment, you may have to have words with your linker, (a miserable exercise, but you may need to do it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a compiler and linker the best opportunity to put an object (such as a structure) in flash, define it with `const` and with static storage duration.

To give it static storage duration, define it outside any function or with `static`. For example, if you have `struct foo`, you might define it with:

```
// Declared at global scope without "static":
//    Has static storage duration, external linkage.
const struct foo Parameters1 = { 3, 4 };

// Declared at global scope with “static":
//    Has static storage duration, internal linkage.
static const struct foo Parameters2 = { 5, 6 };

void foo(void)
{
    // Declared inside a function with "static".
    static const struct foo Parameters3 = { 7, 8 };
    …
}
```

This only gives the object the properties it needs—constant and static storage duration—to allow the compiler and linker to put it in flash. Whether they do is a property of those tools, so you may need to consult their documentation and use command-line switches or other input to those tools to give them specific instructions about this.

You can declare the individual members of a `struct` to be `const`. However, even if all the members are declared `const`, I would not necessarily expect the compiler and linker to treat it the same as if the `struct` were declared `const`.

Comment: very imprecise. This is uC question and the location of the const object depends on the uC architecture. For example AVR-s will place it in the RAM, as FLASH access requires special mechanisms. You can force compiler to place it in the FLASH but you need to use special library (PROGMEM) or compiler extensions like named address spaces. Some other harvard uC do not allow access to program memory at all.

Comment: @P__J__ The question is specifically about STM32 which are ARM Cortex-M.

Answer (score 3):

It is very hardware and implementation specific question.

For example many Harvard architectures will place it in the RAM as access to the FLASH might be not possible or require special means.

Other architectures like ARM will place it in the FLASH memory as they have one address space and can accss the data in program memory directly.

STM32 uC are Cortex core ones and it will be placed in the FLASH memory. It is quaraneed even for the compound or complex datatypes.